# Как сделать несколько событий для одной и той же функции

Tags: javascript

У меня есть обработка событий через focusout. Я добавил туда событие keypress. Как сделать,чтобы отправлялись данные именно при нажатии кнопки enter?

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let inp = document.getElementById('inp');

inp.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  if(e.key === 'Enter') {
    // do some logic
    console.log(e.key);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="inp">
```

Comment: А как мне именно этот код добавить к событию,которое у меня есть? У меня есть on(“change”) я туда добавил ещё keypress. Но почему то не могу,чтобы только при нажатии enter отправлялись данные

Comment: @user328894 для этого же элемента ещё одно событие навесьте. Есть, например, `node.on('change')`, ниже добавьте еще `node.on('keypress')`.